# Genymotion: failed to attach drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

[image]

I did lot of searching in Google but still not solved.

I am using windows 7 Basic x64.

Firstly, it was running perfectly but after I made some changes in vmbox for file sharing it stopped. I did undo but still getting error.. I reinstalled, restarted, and removed but really tired of trying to solve this.

Does anyone know of a proper way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\USB\filter`. Select `VBoxUSBMon.inf` and click the right mouse button. Then choose `Install`
Then go to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv`
Select `VBoxDrv.inf` and click the right mouse button. Then choose `Install`

*`I also had the same problem, did the above and it's working now :)`*

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run as Administator. I had the same problem, but after launching as administator, list of devices already contained three devices

Answer (score -1):

Check settings VirtualBox. If there is a folder with Russian native character, changing the way to avoid this. It happend me.
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: What makes you think is the case, especially with an English screenshot? This is just a wild guess and should be a comment not and answer.